# Scraping entire lines with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm struggling to scrape the entire option lines from a web page

```
<select id="Code_9" name="value[2].valueType" onchange="changeMe(this);">
  <option value="0">Identifier_1</option>
  <option value="1">Identifier_2</option>
  <option value="2">Identifier_3</option>
  <option value="3" selected="">Identifier_4</option>
</select>
```

When running this code:

```
List <HtmlDivision> selectedValue = htmlPage.getByXPath("//*[@id='Code_9']/option");
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedValue.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(selectedValue.get(i));
        }
```

It returns this:

```
HtmlOption[<option value="0">]
HtmlOption[<option value="1">]
HtmlOption[<option value="2">]
HtmlOption[<option value="3" selected="">]
```

But i also need the "identifier". Or i could get a direct copy of everything within "select" and do some string parsing.

Note that the processing time of scraping this should be as low as possible.

Edit (07.01.22): HTMLDivision should be HTMLElement instead. This way @RBRi answer is correct and using selectedValue.get(i).asXml() will output:

```
<option value="0">
  Identifier_1
</option>

<option value="1">
  Identifier_2
</option>

<option value="2">
  Identifier_3
</option>

<option value="3" selected="">
  Identifier_4
</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
selectedValue.get(i).asXml()
```

if you like to have it as string.

Otherwise use getChildNodes() or getChildren().

Comment: Changing HTMLDivision to HTMLElement and using your answer works perfectly. 
Using selectedValue.get(i).asXml() outputs:

<option value="0">
  Identifier_1
</option>

<option value="1">
  Identifier_2
</option>

<option value="2">
  Identifier_3
</option>

<option value="3" selected="">
  Identifier_4
</option>


Note: When using HTMLDivision and using selectedValue.get(i).asXml() it gives the following exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision